# Aspnet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server Error on ASP.net Core 1.0 RTM

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, openid-connect, aspnet-contrib

I just removed ASP.net Core 1.0 RC2 from my machine and installed the RTM as it came out yesterday. I've converted all the versions in project.json to say "1.0.0" instead of with the -rc2-* suffixes.

I think the current ASOS version 1.0.0-beta5-final is at ASP.net Core 1.0 RC2, and it is trying to reference something from RC2 that is no longer on my machine.

I'm getting this error:
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.OpenIdConnectServerExtensions.UseOpenIdConnectServer(IApplicationBuilder app, Action configuration)

I think it's throwing this at my Startup.cs file when I `callapp.UseOpenIdConnectServer(options => { ... });`
I'm wondering if there is a temporary workaround for this until ASOS is released for Core RTM.

Comment: FYI, ASOS beta6 is now on NuGet.org: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server/1.0.0-beta6-final

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** ASOS beta6-final is now available on NuGet.org.

---

> I think the current ASOS version 1.0.0-beta5-final is at ASP.net Core 1.0 RC2, and it is trying to reference something from RC2 that is no longer on my machine.

The issue you're seeing is caused by class name changes in the DI stack: https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/411

> I'm wondering if there is a temporary workaround for this until ASOS is released for Core RTM.

ASOS beta6 will be released in the next few days. In the meantime, you can use the nightly builds: https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnet-contrib

Comment: I updated my project to reference 1.0.0-beta6. There is no longer GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(GrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context) to override. How would I perform this in this new version?

Comment: All the `Grant*` events have been merged into `HandleTokenRequest`: https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server/issues/303